# Reuse DB connection instead of creating new instances for each request

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, instance

I have the following code that works, but I am wondering what would be a better approach to this technique? I would like to start reusing connections instead of creating new instances for each query. 
Any practical advise and solution to my code?

```
<?php
class dbc {
    function openDb() {

        $dbserver = '';
        $dbusername = '';
        $dbpassword = '';
        $dbname = '';

        try {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $dbserver . ';port=3306;dbname=' . $dbname . ';charset=utf8', '' . $dbusername . '', '' . $dbpassword . '', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>"SET SESSION time_zone = 'America/Chicago'"));
            $timezone = "America/Chicago";
            $db->exec("SET time_zone = '{$timezone}'");  

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die("error, please try again");
        }
        return $db;
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php    
require 'dbc.php';

function getDailyProfitability() {
    $db = new dbc();
    $query = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL";
    $stmt = $db->openDb()->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}    
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but I found [this](http://overtag.dk/wordpress/2006/04/re-using-your-database-connection-in-php/) article that talks about using a static variable to store your database connection.